# use "from" property in the linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

in my class i have a property with name "from" but  i can't use it in my linq statement ?

is there any solution or i have to change my property name ?

```
lst1 = (from p in db.adv where p.isShowInMainPage && p.isShowInHeader && (p.from <= DateTime.Now)  orderby p.id descending select p);

lst2= (from p in db.adv where p.isShowInMainPage && !p.isShowInHeader orderby p.id descending select p);
```

when i use **p.from**  compile error occure :

```
Error   14  ; expected
```

in the SQL we could use [] ([from]) . is there any similar thing in LINQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At (@from) in the beginning should work in C#, in VB.NET you use [from]

Answer (score 1):

You could do as @Ales says and use an @ symbol in front of the property name. Alternatively you could rename your property to `From` using Pascal casing - the .NET design guidelines on [capitalisation conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) suggest using Pascal casing for properties.